Probability that a random walk is confined within $y=a$ and $y=-b$ in the first $n$ steps
Suppose we have a simple random walk starting at $y=0$ (at $x=0$), what is the probability that a random walk is confined within $y=a$ and $y=-b$ in the first $n$ steps (exclusive)? More precisely, what is $P(-b<S_k<a)$ for all $1\leq k \leq n$, and $S_k=\sum_1^k X_i$ with $X_i\sim Ber(-1,1)$?
I came up with the following solution but I need to know if there's a way to approximate it efficiently or if there is a more elegant approach (maybe martingales) that gives a nicer solution:
Calculate the complement, that is the probabities during the first $n$ steps we hit $a$ only or $b$ only or both. Call the mentioned probabilities $P_a,P_b,P_{(a,b)}$ respectively. It turns out that $P_{(a,b)}$ is hard to compute combinatorially, so we use $P_{(a,b)}=P(\text{hit} ~a~ \text{in the first n steps})- P_a$. Thus the answer we're seeking is $1-P_a-P_b-P_{(a,b)}=1-P_b - P(\text{hit} ~a~ \text{in the first n steps}).$
Let $k$ be a coordinate  $\leq n$ where we hit $y=a$. If $k<2b+a$, then we couldn't have hit $b$ so the probability is just $C(k,\frac{k+a}{2}) \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k$. Otherwise, use the reflection principle: the number of paths that start at 0, hit $b$ somewhere, and end at $a$ at step $k$ equals the number of paths that start at $-2b$ and end at $a$ at step $k$ which equals $C(k,\frac{k+a}{2}+b)$. Thus
$$P_a = \sum_{k=1}^{2b+a-1}C\left(k,\frac{k+a}{2}\right) \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k + \sum_{k=2b+a}^{n}\left(C\left(k,\frac{k+a}{2}\right)-C\left(k,\frac{k+a}{2}+b\right)\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k$$
$P_b$ is calculated analogously, but $$P(\text{hit} ~a~ \text{in the first n steps})=P(S_n\geq a)+P(S_n<-a)=2P(S_n>a)+P(S_n=a)$$ This also follows from an elementary application of the reflection principle and can be approximated by a normal distribution if $n$ is large enough. Now that we have all the terms, we can compute the required probability.

OP mentioned martingales so here is a martingale approach with the simplification $a=b,b \in \mathbb{N}$ which yields the probability generating function of the first exit time $\tau=\inf\{n:|S_n|=b\}$. For clarity, OP seems to be interested in $P(\tau>n)$. If we define $c(x):=\ln(\sqrt{1/x^2-1}+1/x),x \in (0,1)$ then the processes
$$Y_n^x:=e^{c(x) S_n}x^n,\qquad Z_n^x:=e^{-c(x) S_n}x^n$$
are martingales in the natural filtration $(\mathscr{F}_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ where $\mathscr{F}_n=\sigma(X_k,k\leq n)$. Then consider the process
$$W_n^x:=\frac{Y_n^x+Z_n^x}{2}=x^n\frac{e^{c(x) S_n}+e^{-c(x) S_n}}{2}$$
which is itself a martingale. We know that $P(\tau<\infty)=1$. Optional stopping on $W_{\tau\wedge n}^x$ yields
$$1=E[W_{\tau\wedge n}^x]=\frac{e^{c(x) b}+e^{-c(x) b}}{2}E[x^{\tau}\mathbf{1}_{\{\tau<n\}}]+E\bigg[x^n\frac{e^{c(x) S_n}+e^{-c(x) S_n}}{2}\mathbf{1}_{\{\tau\geq n\}}\bigg]$$
Respectively, MCT and DCT (note: $x^n<1$ and $\frac{e^{c(x) S_n}+e^{-c(x) S_n}}{2}\leq \frac{e^{c(x) b}+e^{-c(x) b}}{2}$ on $\{\tau\geq n\}$) on the rhs yield
$$E[x^{\tau}]=\frac{2}{e^{c(x) b}+e^{-c(x) b}},\,x \in (0,1)$$
